# Express Router.param doesn't work but app.param does

Tags: node.js, express

I've grubbed a couple of lines from express docs to understand how it works:

```
// ./routes/test.js

var router = require('express').Router();


router.param(['id', 'page'], function (req, res, next, value) {
  console.log('CALLED ONLY ONCE with', value);
  next();
});

router.get('/user/:id/:page', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('although this matches');
  next();
});

router.get('/user/:id/:page', function (req, res) {
  console.log('and this matches too');
  res.end();
});


module.exports = router;
```

and mounted them in the usual way: `app.use('/test', require('./routes/test'));`
The problem is that the callback passed in `.param` doesn't get executed. When I change the first line to `var router = require('express')();` it works fine. An app is just a Router with some additional stuff.

I use express `4.12.4`. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like this is a bug, if you don't provide an array of parameters but just a string, it works as expected.

Comment: @robertklep, You are right, thanks. I go to file a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not a bug. It's a bug, but in the docs. A Router doesn't accept an array as the first arg, an app does.

Comment: I am glad I saw your answer! I posted a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337965/express-js-router-process-api-requests-with-multiple-parameters) just a while ago. So if I wanted to handle this using an Express router and two URL parameters, how should I go about?